# Arduino data display in browser and saved to database

Tags: php, netbeans, arduino

I have an Arduino that his sending sensor values to a browser, and I need to store those values in a database, I made a php application for this, but I cant connect my php app to the index file where the sensor values from arduino are being displayed. How can I connect the index file where the arduino his sending data to my php app?

Comment: where is the index file? what did you try that didn't work? error message?

Comment: the index file is in the sd card attached to the arduino, when I run my php app from netbeans the sensor values doesnt appear because its not the same index file.